# How to connect a URL address to image

Tags: c#

I'm back in need of your help again!

I'm new to C#,but I want to learn it.

My new problem is:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://www.jmorganmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/image4.jpg";
    }
```

The above code is loading an image from a URL address. Now I would like to make this image clickable and when it's clicked the default browser should open and show stackoverflow.com (for example)
I guess there should be something with the mouseclick event,but how can I open the URL in the default browser?
Is there a simple way to do this?

HUGE thanks for any reply!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Process.Start("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

will do it. [From the documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Starting a process by specifying its file name is similar to typing the information in the Run dialog box of the Windows Start
>   menu. Therefore, the file name does not need to represent an
>   executable file. It can be of any file type for which the extension
>   has been associated with an application installed on the system. For
>   example the file name can have a .txt extension if you have associated
>   text files with an editor, such as Notepad, or it can have a .doc if
>   you have associated.doc files with a word processing tool, such as
>   Microsoft Word. Similarly, in the same way that the Run dialog box can
>   accept an executable file name with or without the .exe extension, the
>   .exe extension is optional in the fileName parameter. For example, you
>   can set the fileName parameter to either "Notepad.exe" or "Notepad".

So when you start the process with a URI the default browser is launched.

Answer (score 1):

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start([parameter]) will open in the default browser if you pass it a url.